# Sending object from Node.js server to JS client

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My Node.js bot has a main file called "server.js" which receives messages from Discord.

When it receives a message, I want it to send an object (that I will create) to the client.js file, which just controls the HTML page, so that I could display the message.

How can I do that?

P.S.: I'm very new to this, so I would appreciate if you could show an example of the implementation of what you suggest. Thanks!

**What I have tried:**

Currently I'm saving the message in a JSON file and reading it in the client JS file every second. It works, but I want a way to directly send the data as soon as a message is received.

Comment: use socket.io for that

Comment: I suggest to you using websocket

Comment: you need a socket fo that, like socket.io etc